# hamming_loss not support in cross_val_score?

Tags: scikit-learn, hamming-distance

I am using sklearn and skmultilearn to do some research about multilabel.

I was just wondering that why the hamming_loss can not be used in cross_val_score, since it can really be used alone.

Comment: How can you say its not supported? Have you tried using it? Are you getting any error? If yes, then post about it here.

Comment: I just used a string('hamming_loss'), and the crash returns Valid options are ['accuracy', 'adjusted_rand_score', 'average_precision', 'f1', 'f1_macro', 'f1_micro', 'f1_samples', 'f1_weighted', 'neg_log_loss', 'neg_mean_absolute_error', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'neg_median_absolute_error', 'precision', 'precision_macro', 'precision_micro', 'precision_samples', 'precision_weighted', 'r2', 'recall', 'recall_macro', 'recall_micro', 'recall_samples', 'recall_weighted', 'roc_auc' tell me that  may be it does not support. And this is  the third day I use it, may be i should read the doc carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [documentation of cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), it is specified that:

> scoring : string, callable or None, optional, default: None
>
> A string (see model evaluation documentation) or a scorer callable object /
> function with signature scorer(estimator, X, y).

The strings that can be used in this are [specified in section **3.3.1.1** here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values). These strings showed here are internally converted to scoring function objects using the [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html)

The `hamming_loss` is not in those strings, but we can use `make_scorer` on it to define our scoring function object, which can then be used in `cross_val_score()`

Use it like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
output_scores = cross_val_score(lasso, X, y, scoring = make_scorer(hamming_loss,greater_is_better=False))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It just works. But the scores returns is a negative number, should it be a positive number?

Comment: @iromise In case of losses, scores just return the negative of actual score. That is the intended behaviour, when we want to compare two scores. Because in cases of `accuracy` or `f1_score`, the higher score is better, but in case of losses, lower score is better. To handle them both in same way, it returns the negative. Read the section 3.3.1.1 carefully. Just multiply by -1 to return your actual hamming loss values.

Comment: @iromise If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.